# Proof of a special case of Banach's fixed point theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

I have to prove the following special case of the theorem:

Let $f : I \to I$ be Lipschitz continuous on the closed (not bounded) interval $I=[0,\infty)$ with Lipschitz constant $L \lt 1$. Then $f$ has a unique fixed point in $I$ i.e. $\exists^{1} x \in I : f(x) = x$

The steps that I'm supposed to take are:
(i) Show that $f$ can only have one fixed point
(ii) Fix $x_0 \in I$ and define $x_n = f(x_{n-1})$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$; prove that |$x_{n+1} - x_n$| $\leq L^{n} |x_1 - x_0$|
(iii) Show that ($x_n$) is a Cauchy sequence (hint: geometric sequences) 
(iv)Show that x is the limit of $x_n$ as $n$ tends to infinity and that $x \in I$ 
(v)Show that $x$ is a fixed point of $f$

I suppose it seems straightforward but I've fallen at the first hurdle (i.e. part (i)). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First hurdle. Assume $f(x_0)=x_0$ and $f(y_0)=y_0$. If $x_0\neq y_0$. Then $|x_0-y_0|=|f(x_0)-f(y_0)|<|x_0-y_0|$. Impossible.

Comment: Why does that last inequality have to hold?

Comment: Do you know what Lipschitz mean?

Comment: Yes I do, sorry, I just had a total mind blank. How would I continue?

Comment: (ii) induction (iii) geometric sum formula (iv) $I$ is complete (v) uniqueness of limit and sequential continuity of $f$: $f(x)=\lim f(x_n)=\lim x_{n+1}=\lim x_n=x$.

Comment: That's very helpful thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x)=x$ and $f(y)=y$ for some $x\ne y$ with $x,y\in I$, what can you say about $|f(x)-f(y)|$ in comparison to $|x-y|$? Is this possible?

Comment: Of course, because its Lipschitz continuous. How would I go on from there though?

Comment: There's nothing more to show. You assumed that $f$ had more than one fixed point, and derived a contradiction. Thus, $f$ has *at most* one fixed point. You'll show that $f$ has exactly one fixed point in part (v).

Comment: Oh right, I see. thank you very much.